# UIView.animate() does not animate the thing

Tags: swift, xcode, skspritenode

I'm trying to animate sprite resizing. Size changes, but without any animation.

Here's the problematic code:

```
func layout_scene() {
    backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 14/255, green: 145/255, blue: 137/255, alpha: 1.0);

    var char_trail: SKSpriteNode!
    char_trail = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "trail")
    char_trail.size = CGSize(width: frame.width / 8, height: frame.width / 12)
    char_trail.position = CGPoint(x: frame.minX + frame.width / 10,
                                  y: frame.minY + frame.height / 4.4)
    char_trail.zPosition = -0.1

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(fire), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}


@objc func    fire()
{
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
        self.char_trail.size.width += 10
    })
}
```

I expect char_trail size to change smoothly, but it just resizes in a moment. Tell me what I'm doing wrong, please

Answer (score 0):

To animate the size of a view you need to set view.transform instead of directly changing the width to the layer

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0,0);
```

0,0 refers to width,height and this code will only scale down the view until it disappear (not tested). If you want to scale it up till a fixed number you will first have to calculate the scale factor ((width + the_size_you_want_to_add) /  width) -.... Keep in mind that if you dont scale the height in the same factor the view will stretch.

Comment: I can't assign CGAffineTransform to CGSize type. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: can you add more code to your question?. It is not clear why it does not work or what is not working... with more code we may be able to help

Comment: added more code. It's everything that is somehow connected to the problem